# Using Java and Spring Boot and my @Value annotation for my application-dev.properties is not being resolved?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

This is my very first question so I apologize if it is not specific enough (please be gentle haha) and I have already gone through documentation, but I am new to the field and none of it helped.

I am making a simple project that uses Java 18 and Spring Boot to make a call to an external API call and I want to hide my API key that I use for obvious reasons.

As of right now, I have an application-dev.properties file in my resources directory with the following (I am making up the actual key for security) and I have application-dev.properties in my .gitignore file so it doesn't get committed:

```
api-key=someText
```

And I am trying to use that value in my controller like so:

```
@RestController
public class ImageController {

    @Value("${api-key}")
    private String API_KEY;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/image")
    public List<String> getImages(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "4") String request) {

        String url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?" + API_KEY + request;
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

The error I am receiving is this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'imageController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'api-key' in value "${api-key}"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First try with different property like apiKey=sometext.

Comment: I think there is an issue with your property

Comment: I tried changing it to apiKey, but I am receiving the same error. I used the lowercase and kebab format per the documentation suggestions. It mentioned that spring can be more flexible with its loose binding that way.

Comment: I think the two most likely problems are that the file's not in the right place so it hasn't been found or that the `dev` profile isn't active so that your `application-dev.properties` file hasn't been loaded. Can you be more precise about the location of your `application-dev.properties` and any profiles that you have activated? A [complete yet minimal sample](/help/mcve) would be useful here.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Andy! I misunderstood what profiles meant in terms of configuration so you were right, I needed to put the api key info in my application.properties file because I had not set up a profile in my configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you are using `application-dev.properties` therefore you have to do profiling correctly. In your `application.properties` add `spring.profiles.active=dev` to activate dev profile.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answer,
the name of the application-dev.properties file requires that
you activate the "dev" profile or Spring Boot will never read it and the
values therein will not be available to your `@Value` annotation.

Here is a link to a Baeldung article that discusses Spring Boot profiles:
[Spring Boot Profiles at Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)
(I am not associated with Baeldung,
I just like much of their stuff).

If you are not planning to use profiles in your application,
change the name of the properties file to "application.properties".

Comment: Yes! I love Baeldung as well. They are super helpful and very explanative. I appreciate your response and the clarification. Changing the location to the application.properties file worked.